# Getting left-click on tray icon (Python | Pystray)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, system-tray, pystray

I am working on creating a tkinter window when the pystray icon is pressed so I can make my own Menu in the tray. But I have no idea how to get if the tray icon is pressed. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like

```
icon = pystray.Icon(name="exampleapp",icon=image,title="Example",menu=pystray.Menu(
    pystray.MenuItem(text="Left-Click-Action",action=default_function,default=True),
    pystray.MenuItem(text="Other option",other_function)
))
```

So you can set the `default` parameter from a `pystray.MenuItem` object to `True` to make it the left-click function.